# Excel InterOp: Updating pivot table datasource breaks calculated fields

Tags: excel, office-interop, pivot-table

I have Sheet1 which contains all the data and a pivot table in Sheet2 which references this data as the data source. When the data needs refreshing I wipe the data except for the header row and then append the fresh data.

Everything updates fine except for a discount percentage calculated field that ends up with  formula of

=%NAME/%NAME

How do I either programatically reset the formula for the field and force a refresh on that column or otherwise prevent the loss of formula in the first place.

Comment: Is the ultimate source of the data something you can point at using Data>Connections? Like a database table or query, web page, another Excel workbook? If so, you could refresh a table on Sheet1 automatically.